# Maximize ratio of Chernoff divergence to Bhattacharya divergence

Tags: pr.probability

For probability distributions $P, Q$ with pdfs $p, q$, and a parameter $\alpha \in[0,1]$, define

$$C_\alpha(P, Q) = -\ln\left(\sum_x p(x)^\alpha q(x)^{1-\alpha}\right).$$

Then define $C(P, Q) = \max_\alpha C_\alpha(P, Q)$ to be the *Chernoff divergence* and $B(P, Q) := C_{1/2}(P, Q)$ to be the *Bhattacharya divergence*.
Both of these are related to Bayesian hypothesis testing, where they are used to bound the (total) misclassification error of the optimal test distinguishing $P$ and $Q$.
It is known that (asymptotically, in the large-sample regime) $C(P, Q)$ is the correct measure, but $B(P,Q)$ is simpler to compute (see [this](https://github.com/ccanonne/probabilitydistributiontoolbox/blob/master/testing-errorexponent.pdf) for some background).

I am curious how $C$ and $B$ are related.
The previous link establishes the bounds

$$B(P, Q) \leq C(P, Q) \leq 2 B(P, Q).$$

I am in particular curious about how tight the upper bound is.
Looking at [Table 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.4788.pdf) (where $\exp(-B(P,Q))$ and $\exp(C(P, Q))$ are plotted), it appears that $C(P,Q)\approx B(P,Q)$, e.g. the bound

$$\frac{C(P,Q)}{B(P,Q)}\leq 2$$
is quite loose, leading to my question.

> What is the largest value that $\frac{C(P,Q)}{B(P,Q)}$ can take? Can it ever be, say, $\geq 1.5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio
$$r(P,Q):=\frac{C(P,Q)}{B(P,Q)}$$
can take values however close to $2$.

Indeed, suppose that $P(\{0\})=1/2=Q(\{1\})$ and $Q_h(\{0\})=h$ and $Q_h(\{1\})=1-h$, where $h\downarrow0$.

Then for any real $k>0$ and $a_{k,h}:=1-k/\ln(1/h)$
$$r(P,Q_h)\ge\frac{C_{a_{k,h}}(P,Q_h)}{C_{1/2}(P,Q_h)}
\underset{h\downarrow0}\longrightarrow
2\frac{\ln2-\ln(1+e^{-k})}{\ln2}
\underset{k\to\infty}\longrightarrow2.\quad\Box \tag{1}\label{1}$$

---

**Details of the first limit in\eqref{1}:** Let
$$c(a,h):=C_a(P,Q_h)=a\ln2-\ln((1-h)^{1-a}+h^{1-a}).$$
Then
$$c(1/2,h)\to c(1/2,0)=\frac{\ln2}2$$
(as $h\downarrow0$).
Next, with $a=a_{k,h}=1-k/\ln(1/h)$, we have $a\to1$, $(1-h)^{1-a}\to1$, and $h^{1-a}=e^{-k}$, so that
$$c(a,h)=a\ln2-\ln((1-h)^{1-a}+h^{1-a})\to
\ln2-\ln(1+e^{-k}),$$
whence
$$\frac{C_{a_{k,h}}(P,Q_h)}{C_{1/2}(P,Q_h)}
=\frac{c(a,h)}{c(1/2,h)}
\underset{h\downarrow0}\longrightarrow
2\frac{\ln2-\ln(1+e^{-k})}{\ln2}.$$